# How to create dialog with GridLayout?

Tags: android, dialog, android-gridlayout

How to create Dialog, which uses GridLayout and when a user clicks on the item of this layout and then click "choose" button. The item of GridLayout consist of an ImageView. How to realize this Dialog?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1 -Make the custom layout you want

2 - make myDialog class which extends DialogFragment and make it inflate the layout you made

3-in the fragment add the functionality you want

But I am using gridview , gridlayout is simpler but i suggest using gridview

Here the Dialog class

```
public class myDialog extends DialogFragment implements dis_listener {
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_dialog_layout,container,false);
    GridView gv = view.findViewById(R.id.dialog_grid);

    grid_adapt adapt = new grid_adapt(getActivity(),this);
    gv.setAdapter(adapt);
    return view;



}
@Override
public void listen() {
    this.dismiss();
}
}
```

grid_adapt :-

```
public class grid_adapt extends BaseAdapter {
private Context cxt;
//pass the data you want
//private ArrayList<Integers> imgs
private dis_listener img_dismiss;
grid_adapt(Context context,dis_listener dismisser){
    this.cxt = context;
    this.img_dismiss = dismisser;
}
@Override
public int getCount() {
    //return the data length
    //return imgs.length
    return 3;

}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    //return imgs.get(position);
    return position;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    viewHolder vh;
    if(convertView == null) {
        convertView= LayoutInflater.from(cxt).inflate(R.layout.grid_item, parent, false);
        vh = new viewHolder(convertView);
        convertView.setTag(vh);

    }else{
        vh = (viewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }
    vh.button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(cxt,"Open",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
     vh.img.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            img_dismiss.listen();
        }
    });
    return convertView;
}
static class viewHolder{
    private Button button;
    private ImageView img;
    viewHolder(View view){
        button = view.findViewById(R.id.dialog_item_button);
        img = view.findViewById(R.id.img);
    }

}
```

}

The interface has only one method called listen

result:
[image]

Comment: I don't understand how to create custom layout for Dialog, which has GridLayout and how to add functionality. I need code to understand this...help please!

Comment: and when I click on icon how to dismiss dialog?

Answer (score 0):

```
GridView gridView = new GridView(this);
gridView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, your_list));
gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                // do something here
            }
 });
 AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
 builder.setView(gridView);
 builder.setTitle("ALERT BOX WITH GRID");
 builder.show();
```

Try this , This Based On the Single Column, Data Grid ..

If You want the Image, Please Follow this,
https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2012/05/using-dialogfragments.html

Comment: But my dialog isn't grid, which keeps items. It is a simple list